# Spacy - erroneous config.file

Tags: config, spacy, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model

While training *ner* with custom labels, I created a .json file the exact similar way, but with my own data as stated in [the example](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_demo/assets).

Then I tried to convert it (both train/dev) to the binary format needed for training using the command:

```
python -m spacy convert train.json ./ -t spacy
```

which **did** result in creating two files.

The error I got while launching the training process:

> [E923] It looks like there is no proper sample data to initialize the Model of component 'ner'. To check your input data paths and annotation, run: python -m spacy debug data config.cfg

The debug command output is the same.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are overlapping entities. For each word there should be only one tag.

The solution of the problem can be (code from [spacy_convert_script](https://github.com/explosion/projects/pull/38/files#diff-f20ffa19cedd7c97ab89c0eb96c654e57d886be1c67426ee94aa5dbb189801e4R1)):

```python
import srsly
import spacy

for f in ["train.json", "dev.json"]:
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
db = DocBin()
for text, annot in srsly.read_json(f):
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
    ents = []
    try:
        for start, end, label in annot["entities"]:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
            if span is None:
                msg = f"Skipping entity [{start}, {end}, {label}] in the following text because the character span '{doc.text[start:end]}' does not align with token boundaries:\n\n{repr(text)}\n"
                warnings.warn(msg)
            else:
                ents.append(span)
        doc.ents = ents
        db.add(doc)
    except:
        print(doc.text, ents) # See which texts cause the problem
        continue
db.to_disk(f.split('.')[0] + '.spacy')
```

That just would result in skipping the texts which cause problems. To choose one of the overlapping entities:

```python
        try:
        x = 0
        for start, end, label in annot["entities"]:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
            if span is None:
                msg = f"Skipping entity [{start}, {end}, {label}] in the following text because the character span '{doc.text[start:end]}' does not align with token boundaries:\n\n{repr(text)}\n"
                warnings.warn(msg)
            else:
                if start > x and end > x:
                    x = end
                    ents.append(span)
```

Comment: The code as posted in syntactically incorrect (`IndentationError: expected an indented block`). Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70735543/edit), please? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)